# Making a swarm plot using Temporal Series

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn

I would like to do a swarm plot like this:

[image]

The dataframe I have is this:

```
     Vanuau Indonesia HK Japan
1995   10     32      12  32
1996   56     33      23  98
1997   32     31      32  33
1998   75     64      34  65
1999   44     55      55  61
2000   32     45      45  87
2001   32     31      43  44
2002   32     45      34  67
2003   21     10      32  22
2004   75     77      78  79
2005   32     44      45  12
```

In the x axis should be the years and the y axis should be the data from the countries

How could i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data seems to fit a heatmap:

```py
ax = sns.heatmap(data=df.T, annot=True)
for tick in ax.yaxis.get_majorticklabels():
    tick.set_verticalalignment("center")
```

[image: heatmap]

You could create a swarmplot combined with boxplots converting the dataframe to "long form".

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from io import StringIO

data_str = '''     Vanuau Indonesia HK Japan
1995   10     32      12  32
1996   56     33      23  98
1997   32     31      32  33
1998   75     64      34  65
1999   44     55      55  61
2000   32     45      45  87
2001   32     31      43  44
2002   32     45      34  67
2003   21     10      32  22
2004   75     77      78  79
2005   32     44      45  12'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data_str), delim_whitespace=True)

df_melted = df.rename_axis('Year', axis=0).melt(ignore_index=False, var_name='Country',
                                                value_name='Value').reset_index()
sns.boxplot(data=df_melted, x='Value', y='Country')
sns.swarmplot(data=df_melted, x='Value', y='Country', color='black')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: swarmplot]